# pandas - df.max(), more than one max value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to get the max value and column name for a given row (lets say the 1st row for now). What happens when there are multiple instances of the max value?

Here is what I have tried:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'brand A':[1], 'brand B':[3], 'brand C':[3]}, index=['statement 1']) 
result = df2.max(axis=1) 
result.index = df2.idxmax(axis=1) 
brand_name = result.index[0] 
brand_value = result[0] 
print (brand_name, brand_value)
```

which returns:

```
('brand B', 3)
```

What I would like returned

```
(('brand B', 3), ('brand C', 3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `where` to `NaN` all values that aren't the row-wise maximum. Then a simple `stack` drops the `NaN`s going to a long format

```
df2.where(df2.eq(df2.max(1), axis=0)).stack()
#statement 1  brand B    3.0
#             brand C    3.0
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank a lot.